# Пытаюсь создать кнопку-иконку, не получается ;_;

Tags: qml

Пытаюсь создать кнопку-иконку, неполучаеться ;_;

```
import QtQuick 2.12
import QtQuick.Window 2.12
import QtQuick.Controls 1.2
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.2

Window {
    width: 640
    height: 480
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Hello World")



    Button {
        iconSource: "C:\\Open_GL\\qml\\untitled\\raskroika.png"
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        style: ButtonStyle {
            padding {
                left: 0
                right: 0
                top: 0
                bottom: 0
            }
        }

        Rectangle {
            anchors.fill: parent
            color: "black"
            opacity: parent.pressed ? 0.5 : 0
        }
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ошибка у вас в этом коде:

```
iconSource: "C:\\Open_GL\\qml\\untitled\\raskroika.png"
```

По умолчанию файлы берутся из ресурсов, для того чтобы забирать файлы с диска нужно использовать следующий код:

```
iconSource: "file:/C:/Open_GL/qml/untitled/raskroika.png"
```

(Я использую обычно обратные слэши вместо двойных прямых)

Comment: я также использовал `qrc:/raskroika.png` почему то не сработало , так  и не понял почему , хотя эта  картинка присоединена к проекту и лежит как в директории проекта так и в самом релизе.

Comment: Тут  уже надо сам проект смотреть, а именно сам файл qrc. Что у вас там лежит. Я положил файл картинки в тот же каталог, что и файл main.qml. Далее: 'iconSource: "logo.png"' и все работает как надо. Так же хорошо работает и 'iconSource: "qrc:/logo.png"'. Надо еще смотреть какие префиксы стоят у файла картинки в файле ресурсов. Это влияет на полный путь к файлу

Comment: я думаю там проблема в том что нет полноценной поддержки в линукса. Ибо я перепробовал все результаты и прошёл к выводу что проблема не в моих вариантах а именно в линуксе , в винде всё работает (точнее только один метод работает )